# Change in error handling of PyEval_EvalCode between CPython 3.6 and CPython 3.7?

Tags: python-3.6, python-3.7, cpython

Does anyone know if there is a change in how errors with PyEval_EvalCode work in CPython 3.7, compared to CPython 3.6?
Specifically, I am asking because the way errors are handled seems different now.
We have some python code as a PyObject (let's call it Super_py_code), which, in turn, after leaving Python context, might call different Python code (in a new Python context) in the form of a PyObject (let's call it Sub_py_code), and there's an error (syntax error or whatever) at a sub-function, like this:

```
PyEval_EvalCode(Super_py_code, ...)
-> calling, leaving the context now ->
PyEval_EvalCode(Sub_py_code, ...) * <- Error here
```

Up until Python 3.6, I used to get an error indicator (return value NULL, and PyErr_Occurred() / PyErr_Fetch() return useful error information) at both calls to PyEval_EvalCode, which allowed us to string the stack traces together.
With Python 3.7 (and also 3.8), however, I ONLY get an error indicator at the lower PyEval_EvalCode(Sub_py_code, ...), but I get no longer any error information at the calling function PyEval_EvalCode(Super_py_code, ...), so, the stack trace is effectively cut above Sub_py_code.
I couldn't find any information in the Python-documentation for PyEval_EvalCode that the error handling has changed, however, so...
Is this an error in Python, or am I missing something?